# How do I write a function that adds the number of mines around a box and prints the number in that box in python (minesweeper)

Tags: python

Here is the code i have so far. Everything works with test cases. I'm just really bad at coding, so i don't know how to write a function that prints the number of bombs in the surrounding tiles in the designated tile. I was thinking about finding the bomb tiles, and adding 1 to all of the tiles surrounding it, spare tiles that are already bombs. But i don't know how to write this.

code so far

```
def makemat(x):
    for a in range(x):
        list1=[]
        b=0
        while b<x:
            list1.append(0)
            b+=1
        mat1.append(list1)
    for c in range(x):
        list2=[]
        d=0
        while d<x:
            list2.append('-')
            d+=1
        mat2.append(list2)
makemat(8)

def printmat(mat):
    for y in mat:
        print(str(y)+"\t")
printmat(mat1)
print()

def addmines(z):
    count=1
    while count<=z:
        p=randrange(len(mat1))
        t=randrange(len(mat1))
        if mat1[p][t]=="b":
            count+=0
        else:
            mat1[p][t]="b"
            count+=1
    printmat(mat1)
addmines(10)

def addscores():
```

Comment: In what sense does "everything else work"? If you run this, you're just going to get `NameError`s all over the place, because there are some globals that you're counting on but never define.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down into pieces.

1. Given a matrix, row index, and column index, how do you find the neighbors?
2. Given the neighbors, how do you count how many are bombs?
3. How do you go through every row index and every column index of a matrix?

The second and third, you already know how to do, because you're doing similar things in your existing code. But the first one is *almost* easy:

```
for neighbor_row in row-1, row, row+1:
    for neighbor_col in col-1, col, col+1:
```

There are two problems with this trivial code:

1. It will count `(row, col)` as its own neighbor.
2. It will break on the edges of the matrix. If `row` is 0, `row-1` is -1, which is legal but not what you want; if `row` is 7, `row+1` is 8, which will raise an exception.

In this case, you can ignore the first problem—if `(row, col)` isn't a bomb, it won't add to the count, and if it is a bomb, we don't care about the count.

The second one is tricky, but we can solve it by using a `range` instead of explicitly listing the three values, and using `max` and `min` to force the ends of the range to be within bounds:

```
for neighbor_row in range(max(row-1, 0), min(row+1, len(mat)-1)):
```

Now, you just have to finish that double loop, add the checking for bombs and counting and storing the results, then put the whole thing in another double loop that goes over every row and column in the matrix, and you're done.

You may want to consider abstracting things out—you could write this loop as a single call to `itertools.product`, do the counting as a call to `sum` with a generator expression, and then the whole function is only 4 lines, plus you've got a way to reuse parts of it. But get the simple version working first.